# How many points do I need to earn an extra ball?

Tags: peggle, peggle-deluxe

In Peggle Deluxe, if you score enough points on a single shot you are rewarded with an extra ball. How many points do you need to earn an extra ball?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [wiki](https://peggle.fandom.com/wiki/Game_Mechanics#Ball-O-Tron)

> If a player scores 25,000 points on a shot, they earn a free ball. They can get another ball at 75,000 points in the same shot, and a third at 125,000 points.